# Custom Usercontrol TextBlock.text binding

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, binding, user-controls

I have a Custom Usercontrol that has a textblock whose text will change on occasion.
the TextBlocks Code is

XAML:

```
<TextBlock Text="{Binding ElementName=dashboardcounter, Path=Counter}" FontFamily="{Binding ElementName=dashboardcounter, Path=FontFamily}"   HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="17,5,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" FontSize="32" Foreground="#FF5C636C"/>
```

.cs:

```
private static readonly DependencyProperty CounterProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("Counter", typeof(string), typeof(DashboardCounter));

public string Counter
{
    get { return (string)GetValue(CounterProperty); }
    set { SetValue(CounterProperty, value); }
}
```

My Class:

```
private string _errorsCount;
public string ErrorsCount
{
    get { return _errorsCount; }
    set { _errorsCount = value; NotifyPropertyChanged("ErrorsCount"); }
}

public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
private void NotifyPropertyChanged(String propertyName)
{
    PropertyChangedEventHandler handler = PropertyChanged;
    if (null != handler)
    {
      handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }
}
```

Binding of said usercontrol:

```
dashboardCounter.Counter = view.ErrorsCount;
```

The TextBlock shows - absolutly NOTHING.

what am I doing wrong?
the string is dynamic and changes on occasion.
It was originally an Int but I chose it to be string instead and convert my "Count" toString() instead of creating a IValueConverter

Comment: Could it be that ElementName value is case sensitive and that a C maj is missing in your binding : "ElementName=dashboardcounter"?

Comment: x:Name="dashboardcounter" - thats not it

Comment: It works if I set the "counter" directory dashboardCounter.Counter = "sometext";

Comment: By using dashboardCounter.Counter = view.ErrorsCount; are you trying to bind your code behind dependency property to your class property? So that when ErrorsCount is updated, it notifies and updates Counter, that in turn notifies the view/binding?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By using `dashboardCounter.Counter = view.ErrorsCount;` you are just calling the setter of your dependency property, which in turn calls the [DependencyProperty.SetValue](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms597473.aspx) method.

Here's the official description of it (from msdn) :

> Sets the local value of a dependency property, specified by its
>   dependency property identifier.

It sets the local value and that's all (of course following this assignment, your binding and your textblock will be updated of course).

But there's no binding creation between you `Counter` property and your `ErrorsCount` property.

So updating `ErrorsCount` won't update `Counter` and as a result your `TextBlock` won't be updated as well.

In your example, when `dashboardCounter.Counter = view.ErrorsCount;` is called probably during an initialization phase, `Counter` is set to `string.Empty` or `null` (assuming this a the value of `ErrorsCount` at that point) and will remain unchanged. No binding being created, updating `ErrorsCount` won't affect `Counter` or your view.

You have at least 3 solutions to solve your problem :

**1**. Directly bind your `Text` property to the `DependencyProperty` or the "`INotifyPropertyChanged` powered property" that is actually changing (most common case)

**2**. Create the needed binding programmatically by yourself instead of using `dashboardCounter.Counter = view.ErrorsCount;`. You'll find a short official tutorial in [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms742863.aspx) and the code could look as the following one :

```
 Binding yourbinding = new Binding("ErrorsCount");
 myBinding.Source = view;
 BindingOperations.SetBinding(dashboardCounter.nameofyourTextBlock, TextBlock.TextProperty, yourbinding);
```

**3**. And of course, bind your `ErrorsCount` property to your `Counter` property in XAML but i don't know if it would fit your needs :

```
<YourDashboardCounterControl Counter="{Binding Path=ErrorsCount Source=IfYouNeedIt}"
```